# Adding a second y-axis related to the first y-axis

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I hope one of you may be able to help. I have a plot with one y-axis value and one x-axis corresponding to these y values. I want to add a second y-axis on the right hand side of the plot. The values that will appear on the second y-axis are determined through the first y-axis values by some relation: for example, y2 might be `y2 = y1**2 - 100`. How do I make a second y-axis which has its values determined by the y1 values, so that the y2 values correctly align with their y1 values on the y-axis?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### twin axis

Adding a second y axis can be done by creating a twin axes, `ax2 = ax.twinx()`.
The scale of this axes can be set using its limits, `ax2.set_ylim(y2min, y2max)`. The values of `y2min, y2max` can be calculated using some known relationship (e.g. implemented as a function) from the limits of the left axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

x = np.linspace(0,50,101)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=len(x)))+20.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax.plot(x,y, color="#dd0011")
ax.set_ylabel("Temperature [Celsius]")
ax2.set_ylabel("Temperature [Fahrenheit]")

# set twin scale (convert degree celsius to fahrenheit)
T_f = lambda T_c: T_c*1.8 + 32.
# get left axis limits
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
# apply function and set transformed values to right axis limits
ax2.set_ylim((T_f(ymin),T_f(ymax)))
# set an invisible artist to twin axes 
# to prevent falling back to initial values on rescale events
ax2.plot([],[])

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### secondary axis

From matplotlib 3.1 onwards one can use a `secondary_yaxis`. This takes care of synchronizing the limits automatically. As input one needs the conversion function and its inverse.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

x = np.linspace(0,50,101)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=len(x)))+20.

# Convert celsius to Fahrenheit
T_f = lambda T_c: T_c*1.8 + 32.
# Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
T_c = lambda T_f: (T_f - 32.)/1.8

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.secondary_yaxis("right", functions=(T_f, T_c))

ax.plot(x,y, color="#dd0011")
ax.set_ylabel("Temperature [Celsius]")
ax2.set_ylabel("Temperature [Fahrenheit]")

plt.show()
```

The output is the same as above, but as you can see one does not need to set any limits.

Comment: As answered by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909132/2822346), it is possible to synchronize automatically the twin axes with `ax.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax,ax2)`

Comment: @PierreH. That comment is confusing, because in neither of the two options here you want to share any axes.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention that the shared scale only makes sense if the second axes uses a functional formatter to display converted values. In particular for the first example of the answer, this would add `ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x,pos: f"{T_f(x):g}"))`.

Comment: @PierreH. I think that is mostly not desired because it would create odd labels, e.g. in this case labels would be 68, 77, 86. However, if you think there are usecases for this, you are free to provide another answer here with the complete code, because people will probably not understand it from these comments.

Comment: Indeed, I've a biased view from a personal usecase I'm working on. What I proposed makes little sense for °C/°F scales or for the  example of the original question (`y2 = y1**2 - 100`). Sorry for the noise.