# How can I change value on Right axis? (python3/matplotlab)

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I'm plotting a single curve, I use 
    `plt.tick_params(axis = 'y', which = 'both', labelright = True)`
which shows the same value on the right axis as the left Y-axis.

[image: click here to see the plot(sorry I am new registered, not enought reputation)]
Is there a way to change the value on the right axis?
As far as I've searched up to now, most threads are about a shared X-axis. But mine is a single curve, NOT shared axis curves.
I would like to show the percentage of the Y axis value to a base value on the right axis.
I appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you call it left axis and right axis, it really is one single axis. You may decide on which side of the plot to label it through the use of `labelright` and `labelleft` arguments of `tick_params`, which will just determine whether to show the labels or not.

In case you want to show something different on both sides of the plot you need a second axes. An easy method is to use a `twinx` axes. For how to do this see
[Adding a second y-axis related to the first y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149703/adding-a-second-y-axis-related-to-the-first-y-axis).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
```

Now it depends on how you want the two y axes to link to each other. You may share the y axes, or you may set the same limits, or you may calculate the limits of the one depending on the other.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt explaination for "the same axis". Though my case is much more complex than the example, but its thoughts does work.