# add new axes in python plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe containing different kind of data

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[
        [20,69.262295,0.458615,244],
        [40,52.049180,0.105605,488],
        [60,37.380628,0.037798,733],
        [80,28.659161,0.018166,977],
        [100,23.013923,0.004136,1221]],
        columns=['percentage','confidence','threshold','size'])

df
Out[121]: 
   percentage  confidence  threshold  size
0          20   69.262295   0.458615   244
1          40   52.049180   0.105605   488
2          60   37.380628   0.037798   733
3          80   28.659161   0.018166   977
4         100   23.013923   0.004136  1221
```

First I would like to plot percentage vs confidence

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['percentage'],df['confidence'])
plt.ylabel('confidence')
plt.xlabel('percent of population')
```

[image]

Then I would like to modify this figure as follow:

- replace ticks with the percentages and confidences in my dataframe
- add a new y axis on the left representing the corresponding threshold for each confidence
- add a new x axis on the top representing the corresponding size for each percentage

[image]

Comment: Anything you have tried so far? ([ask], [mcve]) See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149703/adding-a-second-y-axis-related-to-the-first-y-axis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to dupicate the axes and to fix the axes' limits for both the original and the duplicated one so that the ticks are aligned.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))
ax.plot(df['percentage'],df['confidence'], marker='o')
ax.set_ylabel('confidence')
ax.set_xlabel('percent of population')

ax.set_xticks(df['percentage'])
ax.set_xticklabels(df['percentage'])
# Force the xaxis limits
ax.set_xlim(df['percentage'].min(), df['percentage'].max())

ax.set_yticks(df['confidence'])
ax.set_yticklabels(["{:.2f}".format(x) for x in df['confidence']])
ax.set_ylim(df['confidence'].min(), df['confidence'].max())

# Duplicate the xaxis, sharing the y one
ax2 = ax.twiny()

# We set the ticks location to 'percentage'
ax2.set_xticks(df['percentage'])
# But we annotate with 'size'
ax2.set_xticklabels(df['size'])
ax2.set_xlabel('size')
# Here too we fix the xaxis limits
ax2.set_xlim(df['percentage'].min(), df['percentage'].max())

# Same for the secondary Y axis
ax3 = ax.twinx()
ax3.set_yticks(df['confidence'])
ax3.set_yticklabels(["{:.2f}".format(x) for x in df['threshold']])
ax3.set_ylabel('threshold')
ax3.set_ylim(df['confidence'].min(), df['confidence'].max())


plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can try so:

```
x = df['percentage']
y = df['confidence']
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_ylabel('confidence')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_ylabel('threshold')
ax2.set_ylim(df['threshold'].max(), df['threshold'].min())
ax3.set_xlabel('size')
ax3.set_xlim(df['size'].min(), df['size'].max())
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to just duplicate the existing axes and give them different tick Labels, namely those of the two futher columns:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['percentage'],df['confidence'])
plt.ylabel('confidence')
plt.xlabel('percent of population')
plt.xticks(df['percentage'])
plt.yticks(df['confidence'])
yt = plt.yticks()
yl = plt.ylim()
plt.twinx()
plt.yticks(yt[0], df['threshold'])
plt.ylim(yl)
plt.ylabel('threshold')
xt = plt.xticks()
xl = plt.xlim()
plt.twiny()
plt.xticks(xt[0], df['size'])
plt.xlim(xl)
plt.xlabel('size')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]