# How to remove a specific tick on axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code. You don't need to read all of them, you can just read the last part start with "ax2". Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

TMAX = np.array([156, 139, 133, 106, 128, 189, 217, 194, 178, 100, 156, 161, 167, 150, 67, 94, 133, 122, 106, 133, 133, 117, 128, 117, 100, 89, 78, 122, 178, 183, 144, 150, 106, 89, 117, 122, 117, 117, 128, 83, 161, 161, 194, 94, 106, 117, 144, 156, 144, 128, 106, 100, 106, 122, 111, 94, 111, 122, 117, 117, 156, 161, 156, 156, 206, 211, 200, 189, 189, 200, 206, 228, 267, 267, 261, 261, 250, 267, 300, 306, 317, 306, 283, 233, 272, 267, 272, 222, 239, 233, 272, 278, 272, 256, 256, 283, 278, 228, 217, 300, 289, 244, 272, 278, 289, 289, 278, 283, 289, 289, 278, 272, 278, 300, 306, 294, 294, 294, 272, 278, 283, 306, 333, 322, 278, 283, 306, 333, 317, 294, 306, 317, 322, 306, 328, 317, 300, 317, 311, 339, 328, 317, 328, 328, 333, 333, 322, 367, 350, 350, 344, 350, 322, 322, 361, 350, 344, 372, 383, 367, 350, 350, 322, 328, 328, 328, 339, 350, 356, 367, 361, 367, 344, 339, 367, 372, 378, 361, 406, 389, 367, 367, 383, 361, 400, 389, 383, 394, 394, 356, 361, 356, 350, 344, 339, 361, 372, 406, 389, 361, 372, 406, 383, 383, 361, 344, 344, 339, 361, 361, 344, 350, 356, 367, 372, 367, 339, 328, 361, 339, 344, 344, 361, 328, 333, 317, 333, 333, 339, 339, 328, 322, 322, 333, 344, 344, 356, 350, 339, 322, 344, 344, 361, 350, 372, 367, 361, 356, 344, 350, 339, 333, 361, 367, 339, 333, 333, 311, 311, 317, 300, 311, 306, 328, 328, 333, 339, 328, 317, 278, 294, 283, 278, 272, 289, 311, 311, 322, 317, 328, 328, 328, 306, 311, 294, 289, 283, 244, 233, 256, 267, 256, 272, 278, 272, 267, 267, 272, 256, 267, 256, 211, 250, 250, 222, 228, 261, 261, 256, 239, 228, 228, 256, 222, 222, 211, 228, 211, 206, 194, 194, 200, 178, 167, 172, 217, 183, 172, 194, 194, 183, 200, 206, 189, 183, 156, 183, 183, 172, 128, 100, 100, 122, 150, 156, 200, 194, 183, 161, 150, 144, 156, 122, 133, 156, 133, 183, 172, 111, 117, 189, 194, 128, 117, 139])
TMIN = np.array([-160, -267, -267, -261, -155, -266, -306, -294, -278, -256, -200, -193, -250, -266, -272, -294, -294, -289, -300, -239, -260, -277, -250, -267, -243, -238, -239, -294, -278, -233, -194, -211, -211, -238, -261, -282, -261, -233, -228, -210, -256, -255, -288, -272, -239, -260, -294, -272, -222, -260, -343, -322, -172, -267, -272, -217, -216, -288, -272, -267, -182, -244, -239, -221, -255, -222, -167, -144, -156, -122, -144, -222, -206, -106, -139, -178, -161, -100, -106, -133, -122, -133, -150, -139, -156, -156, -122, -111, -122, -83, -83, -78, -89, -83, -72, -94, -83, -89, -67, -83, -67, -72, -50, -67, -83, -117, -89, -28, -39, -44, -72, -50, -56, -71, -50, -66, -39, -39, -50, -49, -33, -28, -44, -61, -33, -17, -28, 0, -17, -17, -11, -38, -60, -28, 22, -33, -10, -27, -16, 0, 22, 6, -22, 0, -17, -10, 0, -11, 0, 33, 22, 44, 33, 17, 33, 11, 28, 17, 61, 67, 50, 28, 33, 50, 28, 39, 56, 61, 61, 44, 44, 83, 50, 39, 67, 78, 56, 61, 100, 78, 61, 61, 44, 72, 67, 50, 67, 78, 50, 94, 94, 89, 89, 39, 56, 72, 78, 83, 72, 72, 83, 50, 72, 89, 89, 61, 89, 100, 61, 50, 44, 67, 72, 78, 83, 72, 72, 67, 89, 89, 83, 67, 89, 67, 78, 50, 39, 56, 72, 44, 72, 61, 61, 78, 39, 72, 50, 67, 50, 56, 78, 67, 33, 44, 56, 67, 67, 28, 44, 44, 39, 50, 22, 44, 39, 17, -6, 6, -10, -6, 11, -10, 11, -5, 0, 11, -21, 0, 6, 33, 6, -21, -11, -32, -17, -6, -27, -22, -11, -6, -61, -56, -44, -61, -33, -56, -44, -61, -33, -55, -55, -61, -39, -32, -56, -56, -50, -50, -50, -61, -50, -72, -82, -61, -71, -99, -89, -93, -78, -78, -67, -82, -61, -44, -77, -94, -111, -94, -94, -78, -122, -144, -128, -122, -182, -172, -138, -150, -156, -122, -111, -133, -121, -106, -132, -133, -100, -122, -155, -183, -194, -200, -189, -172, -167, -210, -178, -161, -166, -228, -222, -194, -161, -167, -194, -200, -200, -167, -167, -156, -138, -166, -150, -144, -150])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(TMIN, '-o', TMAX, '-o', ms = 0)
plt.legend(['Max in 2005-14', 'Min in 2005-14'])
plt.gca().fill_between(range(len(TMAX)), TMAX, TMIN, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.25)
plt.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)
plt.ylabel('Temperature (℃)')
plt.title('Record Temperature in Ann Arbor')
plt.margins(x=0)

for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)
x = np.array([365/24,365/8,1826/24,2555/24,1095/8,4015/24,4745/24,1825/8,6205/24,6935/24,2555/8,8395/24])
xticks = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
plt.xticks(x, xticks)
y = np.array([-400,-300,-200,-100,0,100,200,300,400])
yticks = ['- 40','- 30','- 20','- 10','0','10','20','30','40']
plt.yticks(y, yticks)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.set_yticks([-400,-344,-288,-233,-177,-122,-66,-11,44,100,155,211,266,322,377,400])
ax2.set_yticklabels(['- 40','- 30','- 20','- 10','0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100',''])

plt.show()
```

Then here is the plot:

[image: Figure 1: Plot].

I use `twinx()` to create a new axis on the right. However, you can see that there is one useless tick on the top right corner. This is because the ticks have to start and end at the top and bottom. So how can I remove a certain tick on an axis?

Comment: There should not be any need to play with the ticklabels at all. If the question is how to get a second scale in Fahrenheit, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149703/adding-a-second-y-axis-related-to-the-first-y-axis/43149956#43149956).

Comment: Best way is to follow the link commented by ImportanceOfBeingErnest. But if you want a quick fix you can `ax2.set_ylim(-400, 400)` and leave out the last tick without label.Ticks do not have to start and end at the top and bottom.