# Aligning tick coordinates of top and bottom axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment, axes

I would like to build a figure that has on its bottom x-axis one set of ticks and on its top x-axis another set of ticks that is aligned with the bottom ticks. Specifically in my case these are batches and epochs. For every `n` batch points (not necessarily ticks) on the bottom I want an epoch tick on the top. Consider this example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

batches = np.arange(1,101)
epoch_ends = batches[[(i*10)-1 for i in range(1,11)]]
accuracy = np.apply_along_axis(arr=batches, axis=0, func1d=lambda x : x/len(batches))
loss = np.apply_along_axis(arr=batches, axis=0, func1d=lambda x : 1 - (x/len(batches)))

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=1 )
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()

ax1.set_xlabel('batches')
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(1, len(batches)+1, 9))
ax1.set_ylabel('accuracy')
ax1.grid()

ax2.set_ylabel('loss')
ax2.set_yticklabels(np.linspace(3, 10, 9))

ax3.set_xlabel('epochs')
ax3.set_xticks(epoch_ends)
ax3.set_xticklabels(range(1, len(epoch_ends)+1))

acc_plt = ax1.plot(batches, accuracy, color='red', label='acc')
loss_plt = ax2.plot(batches, loss, color='blue', label='loss')

lns = acc_plt+loss_plt
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc=2)

plt.show()
```

`batches` and `epoch_ends` respectively look like this

```
[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100]
[ 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100]
```

So I would like the epoch tick 1 to align with batch x-coorrdiante 10, 2 with 20, etc.

But as you can see in the picture, they do not line up.

[image]

What do I need to change in my code to make this work?

Comment: You have 12 ticks on bottom x axis and only 10 ticks on top x axis. How do you want to align 12 ticks over 10 ticks?

Comment: I don't want to pair up the ticks. I want their scale to match. epoch tick n should be where n*10 is on the bottom axis. There does not need to be a batch tick.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I had the same confusion but the things got clearer in the comments below my answer

Comment: I would recommend establishing a clear relationship between the axes, as shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149703/adding-a-second-y-axis-related-to-the-first-y-axis/43149956#43149956). Else, it's too easy to shoot yourself in the foot. Also, all of this stuff will become much easier in the upcoming matplotlib 3.1 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to align them. The idea is following:

- First plot the data on lower x-axis using (`ax1`)
- Then set the limit of the upper x-axis to be the same as lower x-axis using `ax3.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())`
- Then set the ticks of the upper x-axis at locations corresponding to the lower x-axis values (10, 20, 30, ..., 90, 100)
- Finally, rename the tick labels using `ax3.set_xticklabels()`.

---

Here is the code: I am replacing the parts which are already in your code by a comment `#`.

```
# imports and define data and compute accuracy and loss here

# Initiate figure and axis objects here

ax1.set_xlabel('batches')
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(1, len(batches)+1, 9))
ax1.set_ylabel('accuracy')
ax1.grid()

acc_plt = ax1.plot(batches, accuracy, color='red', label='acc')
loss_plt = ax2.plot(batches, loss, color='blue', label='loss')

ax2.set_ylabel('loss')
ax2.set_yticklabels(np.linspace(3, 10, 9))

new_tick_locations = np.arange(1, 11)*10
new_tick_labels = range(1, 11)

ax3.set_xlabel('epochs')
ax3.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax3.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
ax3.set_xticklabels(new_tick_labels)

# Set legends and show the plot
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, not that is not what I meant. You have for example 10 lined up with 82. But 10 should be lined up with the x-coordiante 100 of the bottom axis. Not with the 10th tick of the bottom axis. I guess I kind of misworded that in my question.

Comment: @lotolmencre: Ok, I think I got it. Check my edited solution

Comment: Now your epoch ticks are not linear anymore. For example 7 should line up with the x-coordinate 70 for the bottom axis.

Comment: @lotolmencre: So you mean, in multiples of 10? 1 with 10, 2 with 20, 3 with 30 and so on?

Comment: @lotolmencre: Let me know if it is still not correct

Comment: Yea, that looks like it. Cool.

Comment: Are you sure, you did not miss anything in the snippet you gave as the modification? When I replace my lines `ax3.set_xlabel('epochs')
ax3.set_xticks(epoch_ends)
ax3.set_xticklabels(range(1, len(epoch_ends)+1))` with your snippet I still get my old figure.

Comment: In fact `ax3.set_xlim()` does not do anything, regardless of arguments.

Comment: In fact, the only change to my code in your snippet, apart from refactoring, *is* the `ax.set_xlim()` call, right? Because your `new_tick_locations` is my `epoch_ends`. and your `new_tick_labels` is my `range(1, len(epoch_ends)+1)`

Comment: @lo tolmencre: yes, you are right. I just realised. :)

Comment: But then you must have missed some other change you made, otherwise I would get your figure as output. Maybe you applied `ax.set_xlim()` also to `ax1`?

Comment: @lotolmencre: Check my edit. I remember now. I moved the plotting commands for ax1 before your set the limits for ax3. This is done to have a consistent `ax1` limits on `ax3` after the data is plotted on `ax1`. You were first setting the limits and then plotting on `ax1` which modifies the tick positions

Answer (score 1):

This looses your control over what the ticks are (you didn't say if that was required or not), but will line up the two x-axes like you said you wanted:
(new lines are commented)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

batches = np.arange(1,101)
epoch_ends = batches[[(i*10)-1 for i in range(1,11)]]
accuracy = np.apply_along_axis(arr=batches, axis=0, func1d=lambda x : x/len(batches))
loss = np.apply_along_axis(arr=batches, axis=0, func1d=lambda x : 1 - (x/len(batches)))

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=1 )
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()

ax1.set_xlabel('batches')
#ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(1, len(batches)+1, 9))
ax1.set_xlim(0, 100)                               # Set xlim
ax1.set_ylabel('accuracy')
ax1.grid()

ax2.set_ylabel('loss')
ax2.set_yticklabels(np.linspace(3, 10, 9))

ax3.set_xlabel('epochs')
#ax3.set_xticks(epoch_ends)
#ax3.set_xticklabels(range(1, len(epoch_ends)+1))
ax3.set_xlim(0, 10)                                # Set xlim

acc_plt = ax1.plot(batches, accuracy, color='red', label='acc')
loss_plt = ax2.plot(batches, loss, color='blue', label='loss')

lns = acc_plt+loss_plt
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc=2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hm, yeah. That is basically what I had in mind. But is there no way of achieving this without losing direct control over what the ticks are?