# Matplotlib: Secondary axis with values mapped from primary axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a graph showing x4 vs y:
[image: graph]

y is the log of some other variable, say q (i.e. y = log(q) )
the value of q is what the layperson will understand when reading this graph.

I want to set up a secondary axis on the right side of the graph, where the lines are at the same vertical position as the left-hand axis, but the label is replaced by the equivalent q value - i.e. exp(y) - to 2 decimal places.

Is there an efficient way to create a secondary axis which does this mapping from the primary y axis?

I'm using `pyplot` from `matplotlib`. Some example starting code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q = np.random.rand(100,)
y = np.log(q)
x4 = np.random.rand(100,)

plt.scatter(x4, y)
```

I want to add a second axis, which has the same vertical positions and spacing as the primary axis, but the labels are replaced by exp(y). Also include an axis label "q".

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion here would be to use a twin axes and share it will the original axes to fix the tick positions. You may then use a `FuncFormatter` to give the ticks the correct labels. The advantage of this is that you do not need to fix the limits of the plot a priori and can freely zoom and pan inside the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter


f = lambda q: np.log(q)
finv = lambda x: np.exp(x)

x = np.random.rand(100,)
y = f(np.random.rand(100,))


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax,ax2)

ax.scatter(x, y)

ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x,pos: f"{finv(x):.2f}"))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, this is great.

Comment: For the shared axes to work, the call to `ax.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax,ax2)` must be done before the plot function.

Comment: `The join function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed`. I didn't immediately get a use of sharex instead to just work

Answer (score 2):

You can use a twin axis. The idea is following:

- Create a twin axis and plot the same data on both the axis. This will make sure that the tick positions are axis limits are same on both y-axis.
- Get the tick labels which are strings, convert them to integers and take their exponent using `np.exp()` rounding them up to 2 decimal places.
- Assign the new labels to the right hand side y-axis
- You also need to mae sure both axes have the same number of ticks and same extents as suggested by @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest in the comments below

---

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(123)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

q = np.random.rand(100,)
y = np.log(q)
x4 = np.random.rand(100,)

ax.scatter(x4, y)
ax.set_xlabel('x4', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=16)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.scatter(x4, y)

ax2.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())
ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
fig.canvas.draw()

labels = [int(i.get_text()[1:-1]) for i in ax2.get_yticklabels()]
labels_new = [np.round(np.exp(i), 2) for i in labels]

ax2.set_yticklabels(labels_new);
ax2.set_ylabel('q', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's a bit dangerous. You just assume that the right axis has the same number of ticks at the same positions without making sure that to always be the case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest: I can set the Limits and ticks to be the same using set and get

Comment: Yes, that would be much better. At least as long as you don't zoom or pan the plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Done :)

Comment: Hi @Sheldore, thanks for your response. I implemented it and it worked great. Just seen ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer too. It's slightly more versatile which is why i set it as the answer.

Comment: @ChrisBrowne: No issues at all. Glad to help :)