# Pass a list of values to a tick constructor in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axis

I have a second x-axis. The x-values are in different units, but correspond to each other (Time and Temperature from an experiment in which the temperature is gradually increased with time).

I have used ax2 = ax.twiny() to get the second x-axis, but I don't want to plot anything on it. I just want to set it's x-ticks. It would be optimal, if I could just pass a list of the time values to the tick constructor of matplotlib and then just get the automatically generated ax2.get_xticks() object of my ax2.twiny() x-axis. Then I could just ax2.set_xticks(AUTO_TICK_CONSTRUCTOR(TIME_VALUES_LIST))

Is there such a constructor and if yes, how do I import it?

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, DSC = plt.subplots(figsize=size)

# Plot the DSC values 
DSC.plot(num_data['Temperature (øC)'],
                 num_data['TG ( mg)'],
                 color='black')

# Create clones of the y and x axes
TGA = DSC.twinx()
TIME = DSC.twiny()

# Plot the TGA values
TGA.plot(num_data['Temperature (øC)'],
         num_data['Heatflow (mW/g)'],
         color='firebrick')

# Set the ticks for TIME
Temp_x_ticks = DSC.get_xticks()

#Time_x_ticks = ??? 
#Use Autoconstructor, bc len(Temp) == len(Time) and corresponding?
#TIME.set_xticks(Time_x_list)

plt.show()
```

Of course I could write something homebrewn, but I'd prefer to just use matplotlib's functionality, if I can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's not clear if you want to have nice ticks for both axes, or if you want to have the ticks at the exact same location, but the labels possibly not so nicely formatted.. e.g. what if 1°C corresponds to 1min:36sec:375ms? Should thatbe the label then? In any case you will of course need a function for conversion. So please provide all the necessary information in the question.

Comment: I want matplotlib to do the formatting for me. You provide it with a long list of values and it automatically produces a nice x-axis (and therefore a suitable .get_xticks() attribute for that ax). The problem is, that I need to plot the values for that. Then I can extract the .get_xticks() attribute, reuse it and hide the plotted values so I'm just left with the xticks for my second x axis.

Instead, I just want to get the .get_xticks() attribute without having to actually plot the values.

Comment: You first need a relationship between temperature and time. I'm still having trouble understanding what exactly you want, but maybe you can explain it by refering to existing solutions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149703/adding-a-second-y-axis-related-to-the-first-y-axis)) and state what you want to have differently. Again make sure your code is reproducible (runnable, [mcve]).

Comment: Basically, if I have Temperatures like this [0,1,2,3,4,5...] and times like this [0,10,20,30,40,50...] I want two x-axes that look like [0,2,4,...] (or whatever matplotlib deems to be the perfect tick separation) and [0,20,40...]. I want to leave the choice of tick separation to matplotlib.

Comment: First things first: I found a better solution. Code below.
Ok, apparently I can't answer my own question, but just fyi: The linked answer is pretty dumb...why on earth would I create a conversion function from correlated time/temperature data, which don't have an easy conversion as Fahrenheit and Celsius have? THEN I need to create an INVERSE of that function, so that I can have my new x-axis? Should I make a linear regression of both datasets to get the conversion function or what?

Comment: The question is closed, because as it stands it asks for something that has already been answered. Unless you're willing to edit the question with a [mcve] and a clear problem, noone will be interested in a solution anyways. A conversion function for discrete data would probably use `numpy.interp`, but one cannot know, due to the lack of completeness of the question.

Comment: def helpplot(X,Y):
   fig2, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    ax.plot(X,Y)
    ticks = ax.get_xticks()
    xmax, xmin = X.max(), X.min()
    plt.close(fig2)
    
    return (ticks,xmax,xmin)


TIME = TGA.twiny()
sec_params = helpplot(num_data['Time (min)'],
                              num_data['Heatflow (mW/g)'])
 TIME.set_xticks(sec_params[0])
 TIME.set_xlim(sec_params[2],sec_params[1])