# Connect the values of the right y axis labels to the values of left y axis labels [Python]

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, graph

I want the right y axis labels to depend on the left y axis labels.

So, for example, if the label on the left side says "100", I want the label on the right side to display "50" on the same height.

In the end the graph is supposed to look like this for example:

[image: Example Graph]

Edit: Here is the requested code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

people = []
for person_id in range(200000):
    people.append(person_id)

iqs = []
for person in people:
    chance = random.uniform(0.1, 100)
    if 0 < chance <= 0.2:
        iqs.append(random.randint(40, 54))
    if 0.2 < chance < 2:
        iqs.append(random.randint(55, 69))
    elif 2 < chance <= 15:
        iqs.append(random.randint(70, 84))
    elif 15 < chance <= 50:
        iqs.append(random.randint(85, 99))
    elif 50 < chance <= 85:
        iqs.append(random.randint(100, 114))
    elif 85 < chance <= 98:
        iqs.append(random.randint(115, 129))
    elif 98 < chance <= 99.8:
        iqs.append(random.randint(130, 144))
    elif 99.8 < chance <= 100:
        iqs.append(random.randint(145, 160))

plt.style.use('seaborn-dark')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(people, iqs, s=0.01)
y_labels = plt.yticks(np.arange(40, 161, 15))

ax.set_title("IQ Generator", fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel("People", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("IQ", fontsize=14)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: you should provide minimal code to set up the graph

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html) will be helpful?

Comment: @mozway I added the code

Comment: @AJH Thanks! I have seen that before but I do not want to add a second graph with new data. I need the labels of the right axis to depend on the labels of the left axis.

Comment: I think the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149703/adding-a-second-y-axis-related-to-the-first-y-axis) does what you want?

Comment: @ AJH Thanks! I will try that out and come back with updates whether it works in my case or not. :)